# Shopify MOTION THEME - Custom Labels On Product Details Page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Ref. custom product labels - https://archetypethemes.co/blogs/support/can-i-add-custom-new-or-coming-soon-labels-to-my-products?_...

The Motion Theme allows custom labels to be displayed on the collection page. However I'm trying to get the same label to appear on the product details page. The value is stored in an attribute.

Example below which shows New Release on the collection page. The same label would appear as an overlay on top of the product image on the product details page. Does anyone know how to do this?